# Unable to connect SUMO with Mininet-wifi

Tags: mininet, sumo

When I run vanet_sumo.py downloaded from https://github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi, it doesn't find SUMO and traCI connection fails.

[image]

I can run run sumo configuration file successfully using sumo-gui -c 'cfg_file.sumocfg' command in command line. I imported sumo class and the error happens here in the code.

[image]

[image]

Sumo version: v1.5
[image]

Ubuntu 22.04

Thank you.

Comment: Where and how did you install sumo? If you run the vanet as root it is possible that it does not find sumo if you have it installed as normal user. Is it necessary to run vanet as root?

Comment: Yes, we need to be root to run vanet_sumo.py. I understood the issue in my case. Actually, the problem is when I print os.environ in checkBinary() method from mininet-wifi/mn-wifi/sumo/sumolib/sumolib.py file, it doesn't showup SUMO_HOME variable. It shows a few env variables. So, I added SUMO_HOME variable using Python3 os library in the code itself before searching for sumo binary in the code. The image was shared below. This way, I resolved the issue. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we need to be root to run vanet_sumo.py. I understood the issue in my case.

Actually, the problem is when I print os.environ in **checkBinary()** method from **mininet-wifi/mn-wifi/sumo/sumolib/sumolib.py** file, it doesn't show up SUMO_HOME variable. It shows a few env variables but not SUMO_HOME env. However, when I print os.environ in general python3 command line, I see SUMO_HOME. This looked strange to me. I couldn't find reason for this.

**Solution :**

So, I added SUMO_HOME variable i.e sumo path using Python3 os library in the code itself before searching for sumo binary in the code. The code change is shared below. This way, I resolved the issue.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I faced the same problem. I tried the solution method you suggested, but the problem still persists. Sumo version: 1.16 and ubuntu 22.04